# Where is the error in my Google Maps Marker code?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Im using google maps, and my code didn't work when I tried to add a marker, anyone can see what's wrong with my code here?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(14.6084, 121.080258
);

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 19,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng( 14.608037, 121.080236 ), 
        new google.maps.LatLng( 14.608154, 121.080277 ), 
        new google.maps.LatLng( 14.608245, 121.080298 ), 
        new google.maps.LatLng( 14.6084, 121.080258 ), 
        new google.maps.LatLng( 14.608543, 121.080148 ), 
        new google.maps.LatLng( 14.608699, 121.080113 ), 
    ];

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng, 
        map: map,
        title:"Hello World!"
    });   

   flightPath.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
```

The script I just added is

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng, 
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```

When I removed that, the script goes well.

Many thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please watch the spelling (capitalization) of `myLatlng` in the definition of the marker. It should be `myLatLng`.